# html onclick popup opens the same link twice

Tags: html

This hyperlink functions as intended but i need it in a popup:

```
<a href="videochat.php?invite={sn_im_chatbox.USERNAME_TO}" class="sn-tooltip" title="Video Chat"><span class="ui-icon sn-im-cbVideochat"></span></a>
```

I tried the following, but it changes the page (like above) AND opens a popup (as intended). Any idea how to prevent it from performing the same function twice?

```
<a href="videochat.php?invite={sn_im_chatbox.USERNAME_TO}" onclick="popup(this.href, 750, 500); return false;" class="sn-tooltip" title="Video Chat"><span class="ui-icon sn-im-cbVideochat"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of the `return false;` in your `onclick` handler use `event.preventDefault()`:

```
<a href="videochat.php?invite={sn_im_chatbox.USERNAME_TO}" 
  onclick="popup(this.href, 750, 500); event.preventDefault();" 
  class="sn-tooltip" title="Video Chat">
    <span class="ui-icon sn-im-cbVideochat"></span>
</a>
```

This should hinder the browser from opening the link regulary when JavaScript is available.

Answer (score -1):

You can just put the URL in the onclick and set the href attribute to `#` or `javascript:void(0)`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('videochat.php?invite={sn_im_chatbox.USERNAME_TO}', 750, 500); return false;" class="sn-tooltip" title="Video Chat"><span class="ui-icon sn-im-cbVideochat"></span></a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup('videochat.php?invite={sn_im_chatbox.USERNAME_TO}', 750, 500); return false;" class="sn-tooltip" title="Video Chat"><span class="ui-icon sn-im-cbVideochat"></span></a>
```

Comment: Agreed, but I appreciate the help j08691

Comment: Cowardly, anonymous downvoter, care to explain what's not correct about this answer?